# How do I access the object args returned from a .NET event from Powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Ok, so I am quite new to powershell and am using it to call a .NET dll I have created, all good thus far until I try to use the Register-ObjectEvent cmdlet. I can attach fine to the custom .NET event I have created but can't seem to access the object passed from the event!

Below is the delegate and event declarations I am using

```
delegate void ReportResult(ProgressUpdate update);
event Delegates.ReportResult ReportProgressEvent
```

then the call which fires the event within the code

```
if (ReportProgressEvent != null)
   ReportProgressEvent(update);
```

How do I read the 'update' object in powershell?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $event in the -Action scriptblock to get access to the event. For example,

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{Path = 'C:\Temp' }
$action = { Write-Host (Split-Path -Path $event.sourceEventArgs.FullPath) }

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action $action
```